# OpenCart: Add categories to main menu?

Tags: php, menu, opencart

I've just installed OpenCart for the first time, deleted all the dummy products and categories it comes with and added my own. However, now nothing appears in my menu - no product categories. I can't seem to fine where to add items to menus.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks

UPDATE:

THis is the php in my header tpl file:

```
?php if ($categories) { ?>
<div id="menu">
  <ul>
    <?php foreach ($categories as $category) { ?>
    <li><a href="<?php echo $category['href']; ?>"><?php echo $category['name']; ?></a>
      <?php if ($category['children']) { ?>
      <div>
        <?php for ($i = 0; $i < count($category['children']);) { ?>
        <ul>
          <?php $j = $i + ceil(count($category['children']) / $category['column']); ?>
          <?php for (; $i < $j; $i++) { ?>
          <?php if (isset($category['children'][$i])) { ?>
          <li><a href="<?php echo $category['children'][$i]['href']; ?>"><?php echo $category['children'][$i]['name']; ?></a></li>
          <?php } ?>
          <?php } ?>
        </ul>
        <?php } ?>
      </div>
      <?php } ?>
    </li>
    <?php } ?>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I have not acutally changed any of it from the original

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a new parent category and sub categories in **Catalog->Category->insert** then add the new product **Catalog->product->insert**. Product should be appear in frond end. for more details see this video tutorials : http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=documentation/screencast

Comment: Thanks but this doesnt really answer my question - I've done all this already. I have products and categories already set up. The issue is that they are not appearing in my main menu

Comment: may i know  catalog->product->product edit in DATA tab -> " Date Available " date ?

Comment: Hi its alright I found it! I was failing to check the check box 'top' in the data tab. I am sure it said that it your video so I will accept the answer